# How to change text within a dataset (div) using javascript (CLASS DOESN'T WORK)

Tags: javascript, html

`<div data-e2e="topBalanceTotal" class="templatesuccess__Wrapper-sc-4pme9a-0 dWpLPl">$0.00</div>`
I want to change the inner text of this class, I use the following to try and do so but the console outputs undefined.
`document.getElementByClassName('templatesuccess__Wrapper-sc-4pme9a-0 dWpLPl').innerHTML = '$100';`
How do I get the following text? Maybe by getting the element by using data-e2e? I'm confused.

Comment: `document.getElementByClassName('templatesuccess__Wrapper-sc-4pme9a-0 dWpLPl')[0].innerHTML = '$100'`

Comment: Thanks! I should've been able to figure this out by myself